# How to create shadow in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to create a shadow like this one?

[image]

Can anybody help me creating a shadow like shown under menu of the image? I'm using Photoshop and is aware of tools but don't know the technique to make it? Thanks

Comment: What did you try? A quick Google search for 'photoshop curved shadow under' pops up somewhat south of 3 *million* hits.

Comment: Also try searching at the top right or refer to the related questions on the right side of this question.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer follow the step by step it may useful....
http://designreviver.com/articles/better-drop-shadows-in-photoshop/